Legality of using the USACE for nationwide solar buildout
Suppose Congress passes the required funding to make the following scenario work.
Would it be legal for the US Army Corps of Engineers to be used by agencies of the federal government to directly build solar panels and battery storage on every willing roof nationwide?
For example, USACE would in some way (perhaps through states) obtain resident or company permission to install solar panels & battery storage on their property’ roof.
Does this run amok of any statutes governing USACE’s function or perhaps the Constitution itself?

Even if it did violate a previous statute, I can imagine a court determining that by allocating funding for the specific project, Congress had implicitly repealed or created an exception to that earlier law.

It's hard to prove a negative, but if congress provided the money and gave the directive, I don't see why it would be an issue. The USACE has developed tons of civilian infrastructure throughout the US. The USACE is not mentioned anywhere in the constitution, so I don't see why there would be any constitutional provision against it. If there were existing statutes against it, those could be superseded by new statutes.
You may be thinking of the Posse Commitatus act which limits the use of the military to enforce the laws of the U.S.However, the Posse Commitatus act specifically allows congress to assign duties to the military as it sees fit:
10 U.S. Code § 275 - Restriction on direct participation by military personnel

Use of Army, Navy, Marine Corps, Air Force, and Space Force as posse
comitatus: Whoever, except in cases and under circumstances expressly
authorized by the Constitution or Act of Congress, willfully uses any
part of the Army, the Navy, the Marine Corps, the Air Force, or the
Space Force as a posse comitatus or otherwise to execute the laws
shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than two years,
or both.

(emphasis mine)
The stated mission of the USACE is

Deliver vital engineering solutions, in collaboration with our
partners, to secure our Nation, energize our economy, and reduce
disaster risk.


"execute the laws" in this context of the pose comitatus act basically means "law enforcement" in the traditional sense, not building things.

@ohwilleke Yes, I guess I wanted to emphasize that even if you somehow shoe horned a solar build out into a law enforcement action, congress could give their OK, and it would be fine. An army base in Alabama sent troops to assist with traffic control following a mass shooting and that was held to be a violation of Posse Commitatus.
